# How to convert a Markdown file into an R DataFrame

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, markdown, xml2

I have the following `markdown` file (md3.md) and I want to convert it into an `R dataframe` using an XML conversion as an intermediary step. It is possible then to use `XML R package` to convert the XML file into a dataframe.

```
# level_1
## level_11
- ind1
- ind2
## level_12
- ind3
# level_2
## level_21
### level_211
- ind4
```

To convert md file to XML I used:

```
library(commonmark)
library(xml2)

md <- readLines("md3.md")
xml <- markdown_xml(md)
write(xml, "md3.xml")
```

but the resulting file is too complex and I don't know how to convert it into a dataframe.
I tried to use the `R XML package` similar to the following but I am not sure how to express the XML file to be converted in the right way:

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

xml_doc <- readLines("md3.xml")

myXML <- xmlParse(xml_doc)
myData <- xmlToDataFrame(myXML, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,) %>%
  mutate_all(~type.convert(., as.is = T))
```

A possible desired output for this dataframe could be the following (I am using tree levels `L_1, L_2, L_3, indicators` as fields for using a relational database):

```
L_1 <- c('level_1', 'level_1', 'level_1', 'level_2')
L_2 <- c('level_11', 'level_11', 'level_12', 'level_21')
L_3 <- c('', '', '', 'level_211')
indicators <- c('ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4')

df <- data.frame(L_1, L_2, L_3, indicators)
df
#>       L_1      L_2       L_3 indicators
#> 1 level_1 level_11                 ind1
#> 2 level_1 level_11                 ind2
#> 3 level_1 level_12                 ind3
#> 4 level_2 level_21 level_211       ind4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly how you would like a structure with multiple nesting levels and different-lengthed elements represented as a rectangular data frame. I guess one way to do it is to have one row with each element's type and content, like this:

```r
library(xml2)

xml_doc  <- readLines("md3.xml")
myXML    <- xml2::read_xml(xml_doc)
elements <- unlist(xml2::as_list(myXML)$`document`); 
data.frame(type = names(elements), contents = as.character(elements))
#>                        type  contents
#> 1              heading.text   level_1
#> 2              heading.text  level_11
#> 3  list.item.paragraph.text      ind1
#> 4  list.item.paragraph.text      ind2
#> 5              heading.text  level_12
#> 6  list.item.paragraph.text      ind3
#> 7              heading.text   level_2
#> 8              heading.text  level_21
#> 9              heading.text level_211
#> 10 list.item.paragraph.text      ind4
```

There are various ways to try to preserve the nesting structure, but they are all a bit arbitrary and artificial unless you have a specific goal in mind. I'm happy to help with achieving this goal if you want to expand your question.

---

**EDIT**

With the desired output now specified by the OP, it is possible to extract the data we need to maintain the nested structure. First we need to extract the "level" attribute as well as any contents from the xml. We can do this with a recursive function:

```r
list_miner <- function(x)
{
  if(!is.null(attr(x, "level"))) return(c(level = attr(x, "level"), x[[1]]))
  if(class(x) == "list") return(lapply(x, list_miner))
  else return(c( x))
}
```

We apply the function like this:

```r
xml_doc  <- readLines("md3.xml")
myXML    <- xml2::read_xml(xml_doc)
xlist    <- xml2::as_list(myXML)
elements <- unlist(lapply(xlist, list_miner))
df       <- data.frame(type = names(elements), contents = as.character(elements))
```

Now `df` contains all the information we need:

```r
#>                                 type  contents
#> 1             document.heading.level         1
#> 2                   document.heading   level_1
#> 3             document.heading.level         2
#> 4                   document.heading  level_11
#> 5  document.list.item.paragraph.text      ind1
#> 6  document.list.item.paragraph.text      ind2
#> 7             document.heading.level         2
#> 8                   document.heading  level_12
#> 9  document.list.item.paragraph.text      ind3
#> 10            document.heading.level         1
#> 11                  document.heading   level_2
#> 12            document.heading.level         2
#> 13                  document.heading  level_21
#> 14            document.heading.level         3
#> 15                  document.heading level_211
#> 16 document.list.item.paragraph.text      ind4
```

Converting it to the correct format requires a lot of mangling, but here is how it might be achieved:

```r
df %>% 
mutate(level1 = cumsum(1 * (type == "document.heading.level" & contents == "1"))) %>% 
group_by(level1) %>% 
mutate(level1text = contents[type == "document.heading"][1]) %>% 
filter(level1 == 0 | seq_along(type) > 2) %>%
mutate(level2 = cumsum(1 * (type == "document.heading.level" & contents == "2"))) %>%
group_by(level1, level2) %>%
mutate(level2text = contents[type == "document.heading"][1]) %>% 
filter(level2 == 0 | seq_along(type) > 2) %>%
mutate(level3 = cumsum(1 * (type == "document.heading.level" & contents == "3"))) %>%
group_by(level1, level2, level3) %>%
mutate(level3text = contents[type == "document.heading"][1]) %>% 
filter(level3 == 0 | seq_along(type) > 2) %>%
ungroup() %>%
select(header_level_1 = level1text, header_level_2 = level2text,
          header_level_3 = level3text, text = contents)
```

Which produces:

```
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   header_level_1 header_level_2 header_level_3 text 
#>   <fct>          <fct>          <fct>          <fct>
#> 1 level_1        level_11       <NA>           ind1 
#> 2 level_1        level_11       <NA>           ind2 
#> 3 level_1        level_12       <NA>           ind3 
#> 4 level_2        level_21       level_211      ind4
```

Comment: Please see the edits of my question. I am trying to obtain a structure to use on a relational database but I have a problem with this incomplete tree. I don't know exactly how to design it.